# Google drive share dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api to upload file on driver which is working fine. Now I want to show share dialog box on my web application. And for this I did the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var CLIENT_ID = 'Client_ID';
  var SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'email',
      'profile',
      // Add other scopes needed by your application.
    ];

  /**
   * Called when the client library is loaded.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {

    checkAuth();
  }

  /**
   * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true,'approval_prompt':'auto'},
        handleAuthResult);
  }

  /**
   * Called when authorization server replies.
   *
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

    if (authResult) {
      // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API
    } else {
      // No access token could be retrieved, force the authorization flow.
      gapi.auth.authorize(
          {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
          handleAuthResult);
    }
  }
```

```
<script>

    init = function() {
        //loadPicker();
     gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true,'approval_prompt':'auto'},
            handleAuthResult);
        s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(); s.setOAuthToken('tokan');
        s.showSettingsDialog();
    s.setItemIds(["<?php echo $_SESSION['file_id']; ?>"]);
    }
   // window.onload = function() {
    function load_set(){
        gapi.load('drive-share', init);

    }
</script>
```

Now I am getting the following error:

> Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

As far as I read the google drive documentation it says it needs 3 things:

- The user is signed in to Google
- The user has installed your app
- The URL of the page that launches the dialog must have the same origin as the Open URL registered for the app.

I am already signed in with my google account.

I am not sure how user can install my app. Is there any code that I need to put into my page?

My url is the same.

Please describe these points clearly. One thing that I notice in my console that my client id is different than the one I put above. Like if my client id is [123].

Then in the console it is showing as:

> Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/sharing/init?id=0B26e8x7MMejoZDRQZm5IOUJvbjQ&forei…nt=postMessage&appId=705048315558&embedOrigin=https%3A%2F%2FMyURL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Need support as soon as possible.

Much appreciated 
Gaurav

Comment: what did you edited @cheryl-simon ?

Comment: You can see that by clicking on the "edited" tag.  I removed an incorrect tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating the share dialog like this:

s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient('YOUR_APP_ID');

... Which is detailed here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#add_the_dialog_script

Do this:

s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient();
s.setOAuthToken('your OAuth token');

Your OAuth token must have either drive or drive.file scope. See the full scopes here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: I did it but still getting same error .And sorry i just mention new code which is also part of script .Could be please do have a look .

Comment: Did you request the scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`? I don't see that in your code above.

Comment: No could you please explain me what is it .I am new and this is the code that i implement into my webpage .

Comment: Please update your code example and I can make recommendations.